# Convert a C++ class to double array

Tags: c++

I have a library that exposes a C++ API that only allows for a double array and a callback function. The callback function accepts the double array. For example

```cpp
typedef (double)FUN(const double *);
double api(const double *arr, FUN callback){
    return FUN(arr);
}
```

However, for my use case, my data is better stored in a custom class and I want to pass an instance of the class to C++ API so that the callback function will operate on this class instance. Is there any way to convert a C++ class instance to double array and then convert it back in the callback function?

Comment: Or convert it to an existing class: std::vector?

Comment: But `api` does not accept `std::vector`. I have no control over the library.

Comment: better create something like `string::c_str`

Comment: is size of array constant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is better solution to create a class which is convertible to `const double*` and constructible from `const double*`, so you can pass your instance to api and let the compiler implicitly do conversion and construct the class in `FUN` callback. I am not sure it fits your needs but im sharing either.

http://cpp.sh/6nlxx

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef double(*FUN)(const double *);
double api(const double *arr, FUN cb){
    return cb( arr );
}

class your_class 
{
    public:
    operator const double*() { return m_data.data(); }
    your_class() = default;
    your_class( const double* data ) {
        // You should somehow know size of the data
        // So you can fill 'm_data' vector with 'data'
    }
    double do_calculations() { 
        double result {};

        // do calculations

        return result; 
    }

    private:

    std::vector<double> m_data;
};

double fn( const double* data )
{
    your_class instance { data };

    return instance.do_calculations();
}

int main()
{
    your_class instance;

    auto result = api( instance , &fn );

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a `void*`. You lose all typesafety with that. You would be better off declaring a specialization of your api that acts on your class instead of a double array.

You should also probably listen to what @BasinhetVeld says. Use a proper container class to hold your data.

Comment: I cannot change `api` unless I hack the library source code, which I do not wish to go for. Does void* also work if I have pointers in my custom class? I thought the program doesn't know how many bytes it should consume to recover the class.

Comment: @KLX Then you can't do it unless you do horrible evil casting things that make the compiler incredibly unhelpful when it comes to dealing with errors. I'm assuming your api function modifies it and then tells you when it's done.

Comment: Not really sure I would recommend working with `void*`s personally, but that could be just me.

Comment: @Chipster That's why I said you lose all typesafety when you pull out `void*` I wouldn't do it either.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to convert a C++ class instance to double array

No. But you can convert a class to a double pointer, which is what the API expects.

> and then convert it back in the callback function?

This is a bit trickier. If the double pointer is to a(n element of a) particular member of a class, and if the class is a standard layout class, then a [container_of](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e9a83bd2322035ed9d7dcf35753d3f984d76c6a5/tools/include/linux/kernel.h#L33) or similar macro can be used to calculate the address of the super object from the offset of the member and obtain a correctly typed pointer.

If those requirements are not satisfied i.e. if the class is not standard layout or if the double array is not a member, then it is not possible to directly find out the owner class. In such case, you could work around the limitation by associating the double pointer with the pointer of the associated object and store the map globally. This is not very pretty.